# Rendering custom error page from admin namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-admin

I have custom error pages in a Rails 4 application and a method in `ApplicationController` that I use in certain places to manually raise a `RoutingError`:

```
def not_found
  raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
end
```

The `ErrorsController` has a `file_not_found` action with a corresponding view.  `routes.rb` has the following content:

```
match '/404', to: 'errors#file_not_found', via: :all
```

All of this allows me to write code such as `not_found unless item.available` in my controllers to force a 404.

I'm currently getting the following error only when I call `not_found` from the admin namespace: `Missing template [project path]/public/404.html`.  How can I use `not_found` from admin using the same views?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ommitted a detail that I didn't think was relevant but turned out to be crucial: I am using `rails_admin`.  While perusing the source for this excellent gem, I noticed that it defines its own `not_found` method [here](https://github.com/ubik86/rails_admin/blob/master/app/controllers/rails_admin/application_controller.rb):

```
def not_found
  render :file => Rails.root.join('public', '404.html'), :layout => false, :status => 404
end
```

To override it, I added the following code in `config/initializers/rails_admin_not_found.rb`:

```
RailsAdmin::ApplicationController.module_eval do
  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
end
```